# Zooming also count as window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
            console.log('resize');
            setheight();
        });
```

I just want to activate when user actually resize the window by draging the edge of the window but not zooming, but it actually activate the function while zoom in and zoom out, how to prevent that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes.However when we zoom in/out the size of the browser changes so the resize event is fired.

Comment: so what should I do? any event listener thats won't fire on zoom but only window resize?

Comment: @FatDogMark - Set a variable that captures the width of the window on load. On the resize event - check that the window width still matches the value captured on load. If false, then trigger whatever is supposed to happen at resize.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the resize event to check for changes in window size like this...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    
    function resizeIt() {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            if ($(window).width() != width) {
                
              alert('resize events');

            }            
        });
    }
  
  resizeIt();
}
```

Comment: actually this won't work bc zooming also change window.innerWidth.

Comment: the correct way is not to use $(window).width() but window.outerWidth, since zooming will change window.innerWidth (and jquery.width() is actually based on window.innerWidth)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Mizok.H the correct way to detect resize is NOT by using `window.innerWidth` as it also gets changed while zooming.
The correct way is to use `window.outerWidth` since it stays unaffected while zooming.
Use the code below:

```
var root = document.documentElement;

screen_size();

window.addEventListener('resize', screen_size);

function screen_size()
{
  root.style.setProperty('--screen-x', window.outerWidth);
  root.style.setProperty('--screen-y', window.outerHeight);
}
```

you can finally use defined variables in your CSS like:

```
width:  calc(1px * var(--screen-x));
height: calc(1px * var(--screen-y));
```